# Problem on terminal of Ubuntu 12.04 LTS

Tags: command-line, vi

I installed Ubuntu 12.04 LTS in Windows 8.1 using vmware workstation. When I open a file in the terminal using `vi filename.c`, the arrow buttons will not work properly, pressing up arrow prints A, down arrow B, right arrow C,left arrow D. How can I overcome this problem?

Comment: What program are you opening? What your describing is perfectly normal behaviour.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add what command you use to open a file in terminal (e.g. `nano`) and what terminal-emulator (e.g. `gnome-terminal`) you use. Besides this, are you holding the `SHIFT` key in the meanwhile? `SHIFT`+`↑` is "A", `SHIFT`+`↓` is "B", `SHIFT`+`→` is "C" and `SHIFT`+`←` is "D", that's normal.

Comment: I use vi command to open a **.c** files,the shift key is not  is working properly.

Comment: Look into your shift key

Answer (score 1):

Your <kbd>Shift</kbd> key is probably stuck.

This can happen because either the keyboard key switch is physically stuck a bit or because the last time you released the key the system did not properly detect it.

Both causes should get eliminated by hitting the key a few times.

It's perfectly normal behaviour that the key combinations <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>↑</kbd>, <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>↓</kbd>, <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>→</kbd> and <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>←</kbd> in a terminal window result in the characters `A`, `B`, `C` and `D` to be printed.